# React Native error: Failed to compile, react native npm indicator

Tags: react-native, npm, compiler-errors, indicator

```
//App.js file
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native'
import LoginPage from './screens/LoginPage'
import React from 'react'
import RoundButton from './components/RoundButton'
import AboutUs from './screens/AboutUs'


export default function App() {

    const saveData = () =>{
        console.log("Hellooo!!");
    }
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>App</Text>
      <LoginPage/>
      <Text>Sasanika Ruwanthi</Text>
      <Button title='click me' onPress={saveData}></Button>
      <RoundButton/>
      <AboutUs/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

```
//RoundButton.js file
import { View, Text} from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import {
  BallIndicator,
  BarIndicator,
  DotIndicator,
  MaterialIndicator,
  PacmanIndicator,
  PulseIndicator,
  SkypeIndicator,
  UIActivityIndicator,
  WaveIndicator,
} from 'react-native-indicators';

export default function RoundButton() {

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>RoundButton</Text>
      <PacmanIndicator color='red'/>
      
      
    </View>
  )

  
}
```

```
//LoginPage.js file
import { View,ActivityIndicator, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export default function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>LoginPage</Text>
      <ActivityIndicator size='large' color= '#ccc'/>
      
    </View>
  )
}
```

```
//AboutUs.js file
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'


export default function AboutUs() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>AboutUs</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

```
//dependencies file
{
  "name": "NewApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

[VS code interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWP1U.png)

Here i'm getting error when this code running in my physical device(mobile phone)

[This is the error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0zxJ.jpg)

I try to run the App but it didn't compiled. It says none of the indicator files are exsisting in the node_module, but I have installed the react native indicator successfully, it is also appearing in the dependencies file.